# Java heap and stack missunderstood

Tags: java, heap-memory, stack-memory

I have read my question one more time and I think the example was not good enought to show where was my confusion. So I will show a different example.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.deleteOtherFoo();
    }
}

public class Foo {

    private OtherFoo otherFoo;

    public Foo() {
        otherFoo = new OtherFoo();
    }

    public void deleteOtherFoo() {
       this.otherFoo = null;
    }
}

public class OtherFoo {
   public OtherFoo() {}
}
```

If I follow what I know about stack and heap, I can say:

[my draw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuZ3v.png)

[image]

in the frame deleteOtherFoo what do I have as parameters? because I know I can only have primitive type or reference type value. In that case I have a reference type Foo.otherFoo ? a value that contain a pointer of a pointer ?

Because when I put this.otherFoo = null, I remove the ref of otherFoo from the object foo.

Comment: *but what happened for doSomeThingInside()?* Another [stack frame](https://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/jvm2.html) is created to invoke the second method, and that second frame is now "top of the stack" (until `doSomethingInside` returns, then the "top" is the implicit return before the end of `doSomething`) and then that first stack frame ends when control returns to `main`.

Comment: 'The invocation' isn't a thing. It doesn't have an existence anywhere. Your title is meaningless.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I did it differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code lives in an entirely different place. Code is effectively unchanging, save some crazy 'reload this class from disk again please' shenanigans (which the JVM does support but that's an entirely different can of worms).

So where does 'the method' live? Well, nowhere. The CODE of the method lives in what used to be called permgen. It's definitely not the stack, never gets garbage collected, and no matter how many Foo objects you make, the code is located in memory only once.

And that's that.. until you call the method.

When you call the method, if it's non-static, it needs 'an instance'. This is, as far as the JVM is concerned, pretty much 100% the same as a parameter: If you call foo.doThingie(a);, then both foo and a are parameters to the doThingie method. These are put on the stack, and then doThingie is executed. Once doThingie finishes execution, the stack is reset to the point before doThingie was invoked, so, 'foo' and 'a' are now gone.

In java, all non-primitives are 'references' which is just javaspeak for 'pointers'. So when I say 'foo and a are on the stack', what I really mean is 'a pointer, into the heap, pointing at the data (i.e., the fields) that represent an instance of Foo, is on the stack'.

Comment: Is that mean all invocated methods are always save in stack with all it parameters before being executed?

Comment: The parameters? Yes. The method itself? It's.. nowhere. There's no such thing as 'where is the method'.

Comment: I edited my question because I think it was not clear; sorry :/